# Setting a static clientId on a asp.net Repeater HtmlTableRow

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I have a Repeater which contains a table row in each ItemTemplate. In my data I have a Guid named EditKey. I'd like to put this EditKey into the id field.

I've attempted to add it in like so:

" clientidmode="Static">

But I get a parser error:

The ID property of a control can only be set using the ID attribute in the tag and a simple value. Example:

I can't manipulate the id in the code-behind. What's the best way of tackling this?

Lloyd

Comment: Can you show some code please?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. I was attempting to have the tr as a server control. I removed the runat="server" and just bound my Guid into the id attribute as plain html. No more complaints from the parser as the clouds parted and the sun began to shine.